# ruby on rails "usr/bin/env: ‘ruby2.3’: No such file or directory"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux-mint

I got some problem when i typing `bundle exec rake db:migrate` on terminal 
then i received the result like `/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby2.3’: No such file or directory

[image]

Comment: check to see which version of ruby you're using with `ruby -v`

Comment: I get the same thing using `ruby 2.3.3p222` and running `bundle exec rake db:migrate` on the official ruby docker container `ruby:2.3.3`.  It makes no sense to me.  Rails 5.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but when running:

```
rails new my_application
```

but after reinstalling the rails gems by:

```
gem install rails
```

it worked just fine and I could run:

```
rails new my_application
bundle install
```

and

```
bundle exec rails s
```

without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was with a cached set of gems (on CircleCI 2.0).  I changed my base image which changed the ruby location.  If you tried to `bundle install` with one ruby, removed it then switched to another, then this appears to cause the problem.