# AppEngine Flexible Ruby environment, application startup error: /usr/bin/env: 'ruby2.5': No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I'm trying to deploy an API-only Rails 5 application to AppEngine Flex w/ the standard Ruby runtime, and I'm getting the following error at the very end:

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error:
/usr/bin/env: 'ruby2.5': No such file or directory
```

I'm specifying ruby '2.5.1' in my Gemfile and I've added an explicit `.ruby-version` file to the root of my project set to 2.5.1 as well.

I have no other debugging information available to me in the logs, no other fancieness. My entrypoint command is:

```
bundle exec rails server Puma -p $PORT
```

I can provide more details if needed, not sure what else might be relevant. Any pointers? As far as I can tell, nothing on my side is asking for a version of ruby that specifically at execution time.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's my app.yaml file

```
entrypoint: bundle exec rails server Puma -p $PORT
env: flex
runtime: ruby
```

UPDATE:

I can verify that I'm having similar problems when trying to exec rake tasks like db:migrate:

```
--------- EXECUTE COMMAND ----------
bundle exec rake db:migrate
/usr/bin/env: 'ruby2.5': No such file or directory
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper:latest" failed: exit status 127
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: When you say _...w/ the standard Ruby runtime..._, what do you mean? Can you please start with this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/rails/appengine#set_up_an_app_engine_flexible_environment_app) and see if it works?

Comment: Hi there, thats exactly what I did and got this problem on the other side. Adding my app.yaml to question.

Comment: In the app.yaml there is also a section like this:                                                              
    `env_variables:
        SECRET_KEY_BASE:  some-generated-key`                                                                   
I think it would be better for you if you follow the tutorial in [this link](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/rails/appengine). I see an `app.yaml` similar to the one you show in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/runtime but this is only an overview of the runtime.

Comment: Hi Victor, I have that section as well, but for obvious reasons I left that out. As mentioned, I followed the tutorial you linked to and this was the result of running gcloud app deploy.

Comment: FWIW rackup did work, the puma change did not, sorry I realize I didn't mention that. My mistake. I saw that for rack systems but wasn't sure that was the best idea for an actual rails project.

Comment: I am glad it worked. Please post it as an answer so that the community can benefit from that example :-)

Comment: Hey so actually I retried this as discussed and it has the exact same error...not working for me.

Comment: Your issue is very similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386726/ruby-on-rails-usr-bin-env-ruby2-3-no-such-file-or-directory Try the solutions suggested there please

Comment: Hi Victor, how would that work in appengine exactly? It runs fine locally so I don't think this would help. Agreed it does sound familiar. I filed a bug with the appengine Ruby-docker project to see if they have any guidance.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce your issue. What you have done (Opening the [issue in github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ruby-docker/issues/150)) is the best thing to do in this case.

Answer (score 3):

OK I now see what has happened after debugging the docker image locally. Because I was on ubuntu and had used system ruby to install gems it had embedded `/usr/bin/env ruby2.5` into every executable script that was bundled into my app. I deleted all gems and switched to rbenv for managing Ruby version which mitigated this odd behavior between unbuntu's ruby and my app.

Comment: I think you can accept you own answer and the community will know the case is solved.

Comment: Do you know how the system pulled `ruby2.5` ? I'm hitting the same issue on a docker image and `which ruby` returns just fine. Not sure where the string `ruby2.5` is coming from.

Comment: Looks like `which ruby` is symlinked to a `ruby2.5` file https://gist.github.com/schneems/c62fc2359983b57d3e27166ed23432f6